# How to export Trassle cap transformation Index into Google Drive?

Tags: google-earth-engine, landsat

I have used the code to calculate  Trassle cap transformation Index form of landsat 8 image. I want to export wetness index in google drive but it showing error `"Error: Image.clipToBoundsAndScale, argument 'input': Invalid type. Expected type: Image. Actual type: ImageCollection. (Error code: 3)" How to correct this error ?

```
 [var calculateTasseledCap = function (image){
  var b = image.select("B2", "B3", "B4", "B5", "B6", "B7");
  //Coefficients are only for Landsat 8 TOA
    var brightness_coefficents= ee.Image(\[0.3029, 0.2786, 0.4733, 0.5599, 0.508, 0.1872\])
  var greenness_coefficents= ee.Image(\[-0.2941, -0.243, -0.5424, 0.7276, 0.0713, -0.1608\]);
  var wetness_coefficents= ee.Image(\[0.1511, 0.1973, 0.3283, 0.3407, -0.7117, -0.4559\]);
  var fourth_coefficents= ee.Image(\[-0.8239, 0.0849, 0.4396, -0.058, 0.2013, -0.2773\]);
  var fifth_coefficents= ee.Image(\[-0.3294, 0.0557, 0.1056, 0.1855, -0.4349, 0.8085\]);
  var sixth_coefficents= ee.Image(\[0.1079, -0.9023, 0.4119, 0.0575, -0.0259, 0.0252\]);

    var brightness = image.expression(
            '(B * BRIGHTNESS)',
            {
                'B':b,
                'BRIGHTNESS': brightness_coefficents
                }
            );
  var greenness = image.expression(
    '(B * GREENNESS)',
            {
                'B':b,
                'GREENNESS': greenness_coefficents
                }
            );
  var wetness = image.expression(
    '(B * WETNESS)',
            {
                'B':b,
                'WETNESS': wetness_coefficents
                }
            );
  var fourth = image.expression(
      '(B * FOURTH)',
        {
          'B':b,
          'FOURTH': fourth_coefficents
          }
        );
  var fifth = image.expression(
      '(B * FIFTH)',
        {
          'B':b,
          'FIFTH': fifth_coefficents
          }
        );
  var sixth = image.expression(
    '(B * SIXTH)',
    {
      'B':b,
      'SIXTH': sixth_coefficents
      }
    );
  brightness = brightness.reduce(ee.call("Reducer.sum"));
    greenness = greenness.reduce(ee.call("Reducer.sum"));
    wetness = wetness.reduce(ee.call("Reducer.sum"));
    fourth = fourth.reduce(ee.call("Reducer.sum"));
    fifth = fifth.reduce(ee.call("Reducer.sum"));
  sixth = sixth.reduce(ee.call("Reducer.sum"));
  var tasseled_cap = ee.Image(brightness).addBands(greenness).addBands(wetness)
                             .addBands(fourth)
                             .addBands(fifth)
                             .addBands(sixth).rename('brightness','greenness','wetness','fourth','fifth','sixth')
  return tasseled_cap;
};

var start_date = "2018-12-30"
var end_date = "2018-12-31"
var cloud_cover = 10

var select_2018 = ee.Image("LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_RT_TOA/LC08_217073_20180613");

Map.centerObject(geometry);

var landsat8_collection = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_TOA')
        .filterDate('2022-02-01', '2022-02-28')
        .filterMetadata('CLOUD_COVER', 'less_than' , cloud_cover)
        .filterBounds(geometry);


var landsat8_tasseled_cap = landsat8_collection.map(calculateTasseledCap);
console.log(landsat8_tasseled_cap.getInfo())
Map.addLayer(landsat8_tasseled_cap,{},'Landsat 8 Tasseled Cap');
Map.addLayer(landsat8_tasseled_cap,{min: 0, max:1, bands:\['brightness'\]},'brightness');
Map.addLayer(landsat8_tasseled_cap,{min: 0, max:1, bands:\['greenness'\]},'greenness');
Map.addLayer(landsat8_tasseled_cap,{min: 0, max:1, bands:\['wetness'\]},'wetness');
Map.addLayer(geometry,{},'Chinese cities bounding boxes');


var TCTwetness = landsat8_tasseled_cap.select('wetness'.mean)
print(TCTwetness)

// Export the image, specifying scale and region.
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: TCTwetness,
  description: 'TCT2022wetness',
  folder: 'TCT',
  scale: 30,
  region: geometry,
  maxPixels: 10e11,
});][1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you were trying to take the mean of the wetness bands here:

```
var TCTwetness = landsat8_tasseled_cap.select('wetness'.mean)
```

But that's both invalid syntax, and now how you do it.
You probably want:

```
var TCTwetness = landsat8_tasseled_cap.select('wetness').mean()
```

(There's a lot of other weird stuff in your code.
For instance, why are you using ee.call in your calculateTasseledCap function?  Why are you escaping all the "[" characters?  Why are you using an expression just to do a multiplication?)